# Can I upload image directly from client browser to CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, content-delivery-network

#### Generally, When i want to cache the image to the CloudFront,

I sent a file to the following method.

```
[ClientBrowser->Origin(EC2)->C/F->Edge location->Caching Complete->Delete Origin Image]
```

#### But, It is impossible? about upload files in the following ways?

```
[ClientBrowser->C/F->Edge location->Caching Complete]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront supports uploads but that's for speeding up file uploads, not for caching them. CloudFront is only going to cache files that exist in the origin server, so you can't upload a file to CloudFront that you want it to cache. You have to put the file on the origin server.

Comment: hmm.. so if i having many custom origin server, may i use them(node.js server)? for example, origin server does not having images/A.jpg, but Custom server having images/A.jpg, this case c/f can recognize them?

Comment: Try to invalidate the Cloud Front Cache and then check.

Comment: @PiyushPatil invalidate?no i wonder can having a split Uploading space

Comment: A "split uploading space" sounds like a terrible idea, and CloudFront won't be able to use multiple origin servers. You probably need to be storing these files in S3 and using that as your origin server.

Comment: @MarkB hmm alright, there is only one way out.. It is hard to explain the situation. anyway so much thanks to answer..!